# BigQuery events_intraday_ tables are being generated daily but no daily events_ table is created

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I've been running the GA4 to BigQuery **Streaming** export for almost a month now because the amount of daily events is bigger than the daily export limit (2.7 mio events VS 1 mio events).

Google docs (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en):
*If the Streaming export option is enabled, a table named events_intraday_YYYYMMDD is created. This table is populated continuously as events are recorded throughout the day. This table is deleted at the end of each day once events_YYYYMMDD is complete.*

According to the docs I should have `events_YYYYMMDD` tables for previous days and `events_intraday_YYYYMMDD` table for current day. But that's not the case - all I'm stuck with are `events_intraday_YYYYMMDD` tables for previous days.

Am I missing something or not reading the docs correctly?
Should I or shouldn't I expect the `events_YYYYMMDD` tables to be automatically created and filled?

If that's the case then I guess I have to take care of doing this backup by myself?

Comment: Yes, you should expect them to be created automatically. This happens on my setup. Suggest you raise directly with Google support as something must be broken!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - will try to do that.