# GA4 streaming export intraday tables exist but not daily tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I've been running the GA4 to BigQuery Streaming export for over a month now because the amount of daily events is bigger than the daily export limit (currently around 1.5 million events per day).

Google docs (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846#tables): If the Streaming export option is enabled, a table named events_intraday_YYYYMMDD is created. This table is populated continuously as events are recorded throughout the day. This table is deleted at the end of each day once events_YYYYMMDD is complete.

According to the docs I should have events_YYYYMMDD tables for previous days and events_intraday_YYYYMMDD table for current day. But that's not the case - all I'm stuck with are events_intraday_YYYYMMDD tables for previous days.

This is the same issue reported in the following posts (I actually copied and pasted from the first post):

[BigQuery events_intraday_ tables are being generated daily but no daily events_ table is created](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73787595/9356367)

[Firebase Analytics doesn't export events table to Bigquery, even though streaming export is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66169932/9356367)

[GA4 exports only intraday tables to BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64976844/9356367)

Unfortunately, none of these posts have a solution and I don't yet have enough reputation here on SO to post a comment to them.  I'm currently not paying for Google support because I'm still evaluating GA4, so I’m hoping someone here can provide an answer (and maybe then I can share it with the other's that had the same problem).

Comment: please provide us an update, were you able to figure this out? So the documentation says:

Standard GA4 properties have a BigQuery Export limit of 1 million events for Daily (batch) exports. There is no limit on the number of events for Streaming export. If your property consistently exceeds the export limit, the daily BigQuery export will be paused and previous days’ exports will not be reprocessed.

Does this mean all I have to do to circumvent the 1 million event daily export limit is to switch from daily batch exports to streaming exports? This is too good to be true.

Comment: From the docs (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en): "You will incur additional BigQuery costs for using streaming export at the rate of $0.05 per gigabyte of data.". So there is a (much smaller than paid GA4) cost to streaming.

I haven't fully figured it out so far though. I have both daily export and streaming selected for now (so I didn't lose any data, I'm still in the 3 days grace period) but then the events_intraday_YYYYMMDD was deleted yesterday. If I disable daily exports will the streaming tables stay as they were or will they be deleted and I lose the data?

Answer (score 0):

The events table is only created and populated when you select the daily option. If you also have the streaming option the streaming data is copied to the events tables throughout the day and then the next day the previous day is loaded into the events table and essentially "topped up". The streaming tables should be static as long as you have a billing account set up and have changed the expiration on the tables and the data set itself.

[This article](https://www.teamsimmer.com/2022/11/15/how-do-i-change-the-table-expiration-in-google-bigquery/#:%7E:text=Update%20the%20expiration%20time%20for%20existing%20tables&text=You%20could%20open%20each%20table,toggle%20the%20expiration%20date%20off.) goes through how to change the expiration on multiple tables at once.

Answer (score 0):

The GA4 to BigQuery daily export has a 1M event limit. In order to avoid this limit, you can look into [Parallel Tracking](https://reflectivedata.com/how-to-avoid-google-analytics-4-ga4-bigquery-export-quota-limit-of-1-million-hits/) which lets you collect unlimited events and export them all into your BigQuery dataset.